# bootloader isolinux/txt.cfg default option not recognized

Tags: system-installation, kickstart, isolinux

I am trying to kickstart an Ubuntu 15.10 installation, but the default option at the boot menu is not picked up for some reason.

The syntax seems fine, and if I manually chose any of the options, It boots as it should, but the problem is that the `default` section on the `isolinux/txt.cfg` is completely neglected and after timeout it boots automatically from the first option.

Here is a sample if the `isolinux/txt.cfg` file:

```
default option2
label option1
  menu label ^1 Kickstart controller
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks/ks-option1.cfg ---
label option2
  menu label ^2 Kickstart compute1
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks/ks-option2.cfg ---
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet ---
```

... so that in this case, it would still boot from the `option1` option.

As a bonus, does someone know how to hide the "pop-up" language selection menu?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to address your main issue, but for the **bonus** I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196874/prevent-language-selection-at-ubuntu-installation) which has an answer that points out the `syslinux/lang` file.  Putting an ISO language in there (like `en` or `fr`) will choose that language instead of giving you the menu.  This fixed *that* issue for me on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.  I have not yet found any authoritative reference for this file.